# DNS not accessing commonly available sites or slow down my browser

Tags: windows-10, dns

I am located in China and I use Google’s DNS (8.8.8.8), DuckDuckGo cannot be accessed. If I use OpenDNS, the Chrome browser cannot translate webpages. DNS Watch will cause the speed of my browser to drop drastically.

The DNS that can be used is either very slow or can’t access some sites (the sites that can’t be accessed by DNS are different from each other, for example, OpenDNS can access DuckDuckGo, but `8.8.8.8` can’t), which makes me have to modify the host file frequently, which is very troublesome.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Saw from your profile you are located in China and that might be the issue: The Chinese government filters your internet connection including DNS. The only real solution is getting a VPN to access the Internet without issue.

Comment: I have considered this scheme, but unfortunately it can provide slower speed and has certain political risks. Do you have such a problem with you now (such as 8.8.8.8 can't access duckduckgo, etc.)

Comment: Many external DNS servers are banned in China. I have seen recommendation for Chinese public DNS `114.114.114.114`. This is the China railway public DNS and is said to be very fast on all Chinese networks. In any case, unless using VPN, you will not escape the deep inspection of your traffic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an DNS issue. Your IP address is visible and location is determined.

As your IP address is detected and websites know you are from China. So the possible solution would be to spoof your IP. You need to look for a VPN server for this. A VPN server will relay your traffic through their gateways and everyone would see the IP address of VPN. But your locale settings may be changed so see the VPN server's location.

But VPN doesn't offer anonymity, so for true anonymity Or you can use ToR browser, to browse through ToR netweork. Here your IP will be really "invisible".

Comment: I have considered this scheme, but unfortunately it can provide slower speed and has certain political risks. Do you have such a problem with you now (such as 8.8.8.8 can't access duckduckgo, etc.)